# Remove Taxonomy Slug when No Taxonomy is Assigned to Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy, slug

I have a custom post type called ‘sets’ and a taxonomy set up under it called ‘project’. Most of the posts under this custom post type will be assigned one project term, but not necessarily. When a project term **has not** been assigned, I end up with a URL such as:

```
example.com/sets/no-project/the-post-name
```

In this case, I would like it to display like this **when no taxonomy is assigned**:

```
example.com/sets/the-post-name
```

## Here's my original code:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'sets_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'sets_permalink', 10, 3);

function sets_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
if (strpos($permalink, '%project%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'project');   
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) 
    $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else $taxonomy_slug = 'no-project';

return str_replace('%project%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

While following the instructions from [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/151778/remove-taxonomy-slug-when-not-assigning-taxonomy-with-custom-post-types?lq=1), I was able to I came up with this:

### Updated code w/ Registered CPT & Taxonomy (Not fully working!)

```
// Register Taxonomy
add_action( 'init', 'create_project_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_project_taxonomies() {

$labels = array(
'name'              => _x( 'Project', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name'     => _x( 'Project', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items'      => __( 'Search Projects' ),
'all_items'         => __( 'All Projects' ),
'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Project' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Project:' ),
'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Project' ),
'update_item'       => __( 'Update Project' ),
'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Project' ),
'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Project Name' ),
'menu_name'         => __( 'Projects' ),
);

$args = array(
'hierarchical'      => true,
'labels'            => $labels,
'_builtin'          => false,
'public'            => true,
'show_ui'           => true,
'with_front'        => false,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var'         => true,

'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'sets' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'project', array('set'), $args );
}


// Project Permalink
add_filter('post_type_link', 'sets_permalink', 10, 3);

function sets_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
if (strpos($permalink, '%project%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

// Get post
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;

// Get taxonomy terms
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'project');   
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) 
$taxonomy_slug  = $terms[0]->slug . '/';
else $taxonomy_slug = '';

return str_replace('%project%/', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
} 



add_action ('init', 'custom_rewrite', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite () {

add_rewrite_rule(  'sets/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?set=$matches[1]', 'top');
flush_rewrite_rules();
}



 // Custom Post Type
 add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
 function create_post_type() {
 register_post_type( 'set',
 array(
   'labels' => array(
     'name' => __( 'Sets' ),
     'all_items'          => __( 'All Sets'.$plural),
     'singular_name' => __( 'Set' ),
     'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Set' ),
   ),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => 'sets',
   'can_export'          => true,
   'publicly_queryable' => true,
   'exclude_from_search' => false,
   'query_var'          => true,
   'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'menu_position' => 8,
   'capability_type'     => 'post',
   'heirarchical' => true,
   'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-playlist-audio',
   'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sets/%project%', 'with_front' => false ),
   'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
   'register_meta_box_cb' => 'set_meta_boxes',

   )
  );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
 }
```

## The Problem

The updated code *appears* to work correctly. However, when trying to view a post that has no taxonomy assigned, I run into a weird problem. For example, **this URL works but it returns a 404 page**:

```
example.com/sets/the-post-name
```

It seems as if the actual post for the previous URL shows up at:

```
example.com/sets/project/the-post-name
```

But as stated above, **I need it to display like this when no taxonomy is assigned**:

```
example.com/sets/the-post-name
```

Now when I assign a taxonomy with the slug named, "**groove-sessions**" to the post, everything displays perfectly and the link does not show a 404 page. For example, **this URL works**:

```
example.com/sets/groove-sessions/the-post-name
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? Like, is there a way to make it ignore the whole %project%  when no taxonomy term is assigned? Thanks.

Thanks!

Comment: your rewrite rule should be `index.php?sets=$matches[1]`, you're loading a sets post, not a project term.

Comment: Hey @Milo, thanks for tip. That worked fine but it seems like it has the same results. What I noticed is that with or without the rewrite rule function, (and no taxonomy is assigned of course) the URL in the address bar still shows up as `example.com/sets/project/the-post-name`, which is what I don't want to happen.

Comment: You see `project` or `%project%` in the URL? If the URLs are not output correctly, the issue is with your `post_type_link` function. Also note that you only need to filter `post_type_link`, not `post_link`, which is only for the `post` post type.

Comment: @Milo, `project` _only_ appears in the URL when there is _no taxonomy assigned_. Also, I removed the `post_link` filter, still no luck.

Comment: well again, your `post_type_link` filter isn't working correctly if that's the case. I don't understand why the `%` delimiters would be removed either, which leads me to believe you've got other code interfering or what you have above isn't exactly what's in your live code. if you can provide a full set of code that registers your post type and taxonomy in a form I can copy and paste I can test things, but I can't otherwise reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Milo, I have provided the full set of code that includes the post type and taxonomy both registered. Check it out above. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but I think I may see the issue here- your taxonomy term URLs are the same pattern as the posts without taxonomy term. You'll have to change the term URLs, or hook query parsing and check what the request is supposed to be for and manipulate query vars so both types of queries can succeed. I think I've written an answer about that in the past if you want to look around here. I'm out the door right now and won't be able to look further until tomorrow.

Comment: Hello @Milo, Have you tested out the code to see what you can do with it? I tried searching around and tested a few things that you said, but I'm not really sure what to search for or try out it seems.

Comment: Your cpt code references `set_meta_boxes` as a meta box callback, which is missing, so I commented that line out. The URLs are formed correctly both with and without project terms, so I can't replicate the issue you speak of. As I mentioned earlier, the ones without a project term don't work because WordPress is trying to query for a project term matching the set slug. [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177015/4771) explains a fix for that, but note that it requires extra database queries for every request to those URLs. A better solution is to make those term URLs unique.

Comment: @Milo So let me get this clear, if I use that answer, every time someone visits one of those URLs, a new database table will be formed?

Comment: no, the database will be queried to determine if it's a term first, then if not, for the post. so basically- "hey, is this a term in the taxonomy? no? ok, then is this a post in the posts table?". so 2 queries instead of 1 for each post view. it's not a major hit, it's just a little extra load you can remove if you make the term URLs a unique pattern.

Comment: check out the last code block in [this tutorial](http://colorlabsproject.com/tutorials/remove-slugs-custom-post-type-url/). seems like you will have to proceed similar by using `pre_get_posts` to re-insert the missing /no-project/ slug into the query when no term is assigned. [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With helpful tips from Milo, I was able to remove the taxonomy slug when no taxonomy is assigned to the custom post type by adding the following code to the updated functions above:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'project_request_filter' );
function project_request_filter( $request ){
if( array_key_exists( 'project' , $request )
    && ! get_term_by( 'slug', $request['project'], 'project' ) ){
        $request['set'] = $request['project'];
        $request['name'] = $request['project'];
        $request['post_type'] = 'set';
        unset( $request['project'] );
}
return $request;
}
```